# How to verify a Google API App without a Restricted Scope?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to verify my google OAuth app. I am **ONLY** using email address for public OAuth sign in to my app. ,I do not use any Google APIS besides oauth with scope:email. My OAuth Consent Screen for my app on Google Cloud gives me a warning:

**Action Required:**
Comply with domain verification requirements.
Ensure your application's domains have completed the Search Console verification process

Currently the OAuth registration/login works on my website with any google account. Seems to be working fine but I dont want my functionality cut off by google because Im not verified. From the [current documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-process&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-requirements-for-verification%2Chow-do-i-determine-if-i-need-to-submit-my-app-for-restricted-scope-verification), it says:

**Homepage requirements**

- Your homepage must link to an externally accessible domain that describes the necessary content, context, or connection to the app you are submitting.
- Your homepage must not be a link to a sign-in page.
- Your homepage must explain with transparency the purpose for which your application requests user data.
- Your homepage must thoroughly describe how your app enhances user functionality.
- Your homepage must be accurate, inclusive, and easily accessible to all users.
- Your Privacy Policy must be accessible from your homepage URL and visible to users. -
  The Privacy Policy must clearly disclose the manner in which your application accesses, uses, stores, or shares Google user data.

This is very vague and Im not sure what they are asking. Can someone explain practically what I need to do to my homepage to get it approved and verified by google? And is this an automated or manual (someone at google looking at it) process? What should i literally add to my homepage to fulfill these requirements?

Comment: Did you verify your domain?